# Interaction between networkx and matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying networkx and visualization in matplotlib an I'm confused becouse I do not clearly understand how do they interact with each other?
There simple example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import networkx as nx
G=nx.path_graph(8)
nx.draw(G)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Where do I tell pyplot, that I want to draw graph G?
I guess  that nx.draw use something like matplotlib.pyplot.{plot, etc ...}
So, if I want to draw 2 graphs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import networkx as nx

G=nx.path_graph(8)
E=nx.path_graph(30)
nx.draw(G)

matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
nx.draw(E)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Then... little experiment

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.path_graph(8)
E=nx.path_graph(30)
nx.draw(G)
import matplotlib.pyplot
matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
nx.draw(E)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

Please don't kill me about this stupid code, I am just trying to understand - how do networkx draw something  matplotlib, while it even doesn't import yet!

P.S: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just create two different axes if you want to draw the graphs separately or create a single `Axes` object an pass it to `nx.draw`. For example:

```
G = nx.path_graph(8)
E = nx.path_graph(30)

# one plot, both graphs
fig, ax = subplots()
nx.draw(G, ax=ax)
nx.draw(E, ax=ax)
```

to get:

[image]

If you want two *different* figure objects then create them separately, like so:

```
G = nx.path_graph(8)
E = nx.path_graph(30)

# two separate graphs
fig1 = figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
nx.draw(G, ax=ax1)

fig2 = figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
nx.draw(G, ax=ax2)
```

yielding:

[image]
[image]

Finally, you could create a subplot if you wanted, like this:

```
G = nx.path_graph(8)
E = nx.path_graph(30)

pos=nx.spring_layout(E,iterations=100)

subplot(121)
nx.draw(E, pos)

subplot(122)
nx.draw(G, pos)
```

resulting in:

[image]

For whatever it's worth it looks like the `ax` argument to `nx.draw` is useless with `matplotlib`'s API **when you want to create subplots outside of `pylab`**, because `nx.draw` has some calls to `gca` which makes it dependent on the `pylab` interface. Didn't really dig into why that is, just thought I would point it out.

The source code to `nx.draw` is fairly straightforward:

```
try:
    import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError("Matplotlib required for draw()")
except RuntimeError:
    print("Matplotlib unable to open display")
    raise

cf=pylab.gcf()
cf.set_facecolor('w')
if ax is None:
    if cf._axstack() is None:
        ax=cf.add_axes((0,0,1,1))
    else:
        ax=cf.gca()

# allow callers to override the hold state by passing hold=True|False

b = pylab.ishold()
h = kwds.pop('hold', None)
if h is not None:
    pylab.hold(h)
try:
    draw_networkx(G,pos=pos,ax=ax,**kwds)
    ax.set_axis_off()
    pylab.draw_if_interactive()
except:
    pylab.hold(b)
    raise
pylab.hold(b)
return
```

1. A figure is captured from the environment using `gcf`.
2. Then an `Axes` object is added to the figure if one doesn't exist, otherwise get it from the environment using `gca`.
3. Make the plot face color white
4. turn `hold` on
5. draw it with an internal function
6. turn off the axes
7. lastly if we're in interactive mode, draw it and reraise any exceptions that were caught