# NetworkX and pyplot subplotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm generating graphs using NetworkX and I plot some data using pyplot. Can I show them on one plot using subplot or something similar?
I managed to subplot two pyplot-generated plots on one figure, I can't get two NetworkX-generated, nor mixed.

Here's the example code I'm testing it on:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [3,2,5,7,3,6,8,5,2,5]

fig = plt.figure()
sp1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
sp1.plot(x,y)
sp2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2,color='r',weight=2)
G.add_edge(2,3,color='b',weight=4)
G.add_edge(3,4,color='g',weight=6)

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

edges = G.edges()
colors = [G[u][v]['color'] for u,v in edges]
weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]

# nx.draw(G, pos, edges=edges, edge_color=colors, width=weights)

sp2.draw(G)

plt.show()
```

Comment: `nx.draw` has an `ax` argument for this kind of situations: `nx.draw(G, pos, ax=sp2, ...)`

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed it reading through the reference pdf. It does work perfectly now, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interaction between networkx and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563766/interaction-between-networkx-and-matplotlib)

Comment: Yes, as well. I only needed the ax argument though. Thanks anyway!